# Placing of Cells next to each other instead of under each other

Tags: html, css, cells

I'm currently working on a project and I need to make the cells of my table appear like below:

```
|       |   [Cell One] [Cell Two]
| Image | 
|       | [Cell Three] [Cell Four]
```

Despite googling and reading my textbook, I can't seem to find a way to do so, as my code is telling doing this:

```
|       | [ Cell One]
|       | [ Cell Two]
| Image | [ Cell Three] 
|       | [ Cell Four]
```

Is there a way to fix this with a CSS syntax, HTML Tag or something of that degree that I missed?

Comment: I don't know because you haven't shown us your HTML or CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to utilise rowspan for this to work in a HTML fashion, like so:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="4"><!-- Image here --></td>
    <td rowspan="1"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="1"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="1"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="1"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

See jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/dhvnP/

you could also do something akin to this, but note the layout is purely for illustration you can play with it and make it work for you, i prefer a table-less layout, if indeed you are making a layout: http://jsfiddle.net/NRsbV/

Comment: Ah that makes sense, sorry for being a dumb!

Comment: Not dumb, it is a bit of a think to suddenly come up with this if you have not seen it before.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you are forgetting the < tr> tags, correct table syntax:

```
<img style="float:left" src="images/custom_br.png" alt="img">
<table style="float:left" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>row 1, cell 1</td>
        <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row 2, cell 1</td>
        <td>row 2, cell 2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This works as you want.

Comment: +1 This is a decent answer, easier to understand than my answer.